# Invertendo Ordem coluna data.frame

Tags: r, data.frame

Tenho esse data frame:

```
> head(df1)
         data    spread
1 2006-01-01   -3.0404577
2 2006-02-01   -3.3902628
3 2006-03-01   -2.5283960
4 2006-04-01   -1.5279234
5 2006-05-01   -0.0897918
6 2006-06-01    1.0286549
> tail(df1)
         data    spread
112 2015-04-01   -0.2923391
113 2015-05-01   -0.8202538
114 2015-06-01   -1.0975489
115 2015-07-01   -1.1600462
116 2015-08-01   -0.4637534
117 2015-09-01    1.2141885
```

Quero inverter a ordem da coluna e dos dados:

Fiz esse comando:

```
df1<-df1[order(rev(df1$data),rev(df1$spread)),]
```

Ele embaralha e deixa desorganizado:

```
> head(df1)
      data          spread
114 jun2015 -1.09754890
110 fev2015  0.06755755
106 out2014  0.87560496
116 ago2015 -0.46375344
117 set2015  1.21418847
111 mar2015  0.32772727
> tail(MatrizVerticeSpreadMensala)
      data          spread
9 set2006  0.0742353
3 mar2006 -2.5283960
4 abr2006 -1.5279234
5 mai2006 -0.0897918
7 jul2006  0.5451561
1 jan2006 -3.0404577
```

Alguma sugestão?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recriando sua base de dados

```
df<- read.table(text="data    spread
1 2006-01-01   -3.0404577
2 2006-02-01   -3.3902628
3 2006-03-01   -2.5283960
4 2006-04-01   -1.5279234
5 2006-05-01   -0.0897918
6 2006-06-01    1.0286549
112 2015-04-01   -0.2923391
113 2015-05-01   -0.8202538
114 2015-06-01   -1.0975489
115 2015-07-01   -1.1600462
116 2015-08-01   -0.4637534
117 2015-09-01    1.2141885")
```

Utilizando o comando `rev()` para fazer o desejado (inverter a ordem das colunas e dos dados).

```
rev(df[nrow(df):1,])

        spread       data
117  1.2141885 2015-09-01
116 -0.4637534 2015-08-01
115 -1.1600462 2015-07-01
114 -1.0975489 2015-06-01
113 -0.8202538 2015-05-01
112 -0.2923391 2015-04-01
6    1.0286549 2006-06-01
5   -0.0897918 2006-05-01
4   -1.5279234 2006-04-01
3   -2.5283960 2006-03-01
2   -3.3902628 2006-02-01
1   -3.0404577 2006-01-01
```

Answer (score 1):

De forma hipotética, recriei seus dados utilizando os pacotes `lubridate` e `dylyr`.

```
library (lubridate)
dados<-data.frame(data=seq(ymd('2006/01/01'),ymd('2015/09/01'),by='1 month'),spread=rnorm(117))
```

Para inverter, neste caso simplesmente reordenando as datas, apliquei a seguinte expressão:

```
library (dplyr)                  
dados_ordenados<-dados %>% arrange(desc(data))
```

Onde:

- %>% é um *operador pipe que simplifica a expressão f(x)*;
- arrange é uma função de ordenamento e;
- desc organiza na ordem decrescente.

E para reposicionar suas colunas:

```
posicao_dados<- dados_ordenados  %>%  select(spread, everything())
```

Onde:

- everything() é tudo o resto.

Comment: A resposta não está necessariamente correta: 1. O AP pediu para inverter a coluna, não ordenar de forma diferente. Realmente parece ter o mesmo resultado, mas não foi o perguntado, para uma pessoa procurando apenas como inverter a ordem estaria errado. 2. Ele também pediu para inverter as colunas, neste caso apenas a ordem das linhas foi modificada.

Comment: Entendido, assim que puder vou corrigir a resposta. Obrigado!